# Product, homomorphism and kernel of these two additive matrices groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-homomorphism

Consider the additive groups $\mathit{G}:= \mathfrak{M}_{\mathrm{4x1}}(\mathbb{Z_{11}})$ and $\mathit{H}:= \mathfrak{M}_{\mathrm{3x1}}(\mathbb{Z_{11}})$ (column matrices with height 4 and 3 respectively). Suppose that $\mathbf{a}$ is a fixed matrix such that $\mathbf{a} :=$$\left(\begin{matrix}2&7&2&4 \\3&5&1&2 \\ 5&1&8&5\end{matrix}\right) \in \mathfrak{M}_{\mathrm{4x3}}(\mathbb{Z_{11}})$, consider the function:

$\mathit{f}_a:\mathit{G} \to \mathit{H}$

$\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{a  \cdot x }$

($\mathbf{a  \cdot x}$ is, of course, product of matrix $\mathbf{a}$ by column matrix $\mathbf{x}$).

1) Prove that $\mathit{f}_a$ is a homomorphism of additive groups and determine kernel and its cardinality;

2) demonstrate if the element $\mathbf{y} := $$\left(\begin{matrix}4\\6 \\10 \end{matrix}\right) \in \mathit{H}$ is in the image of $\mathit{f}_a $.

So, I had this problem during my Discrete Mathematics test months ago (which I passed), but i couldn't solve this particular problem, I solved many exercises with Group Theory, Matrices etc, but this one is a merge of two different argument and I was mentally imprepared for that. I never ever tried to solve it, I just wanted to know the answer and the process behind it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be straight forward to check that a linear mapping is a homomorphism. Row-reduce in $\Bbb Z_{11}$ to find the kernel.  The cardinality should be $11^{\operatorname {nullity}}$.

For part b, row-reduce the augmented matrix in $\Bbb Z_{11}$.

So, for starters,  $2^{-1}\cong6\pmod {11}$.  So multiply the first row by $6$.  Get a $1$ on the pivot, and use it to clear the first column.  Now do the same for the second pivot and column.  Continue...

Here's what I got:  $\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}2&7&2&2&4\\3&5&1&2&6\\5&1&8&5&10\end{array}\right)\to\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}1&9&1&2&2\\0&0&9&7&0\\0&1&8&5&10\end{array}\right) \to\left(\begin{array}{rrrr|r}1&0&6&1&0\\0&1&8&5&10\\0&0&9&7&0\end{array}\right)\to\left (\begin{array}{rrrr|r}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&4&10\\0&0&1&2&0\end{array}\right) $.

Now we back-substitute:   get $\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\-4t+10\\-2t\\t\end{pmatrix}, t\in\Bbb Z_{11}\}$.

So the answer to the last question is yes.  For instance,  $f_a\begin{pmatrix}0\\10\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}4\\6\\10\end{pmatrix}$.

And, the rank is $3$.  So the nullity is $1$ and the cardinality of the kernel is $11$.  The kernel is $\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\-4t\\-2t\\t\end{pmatrix}\,,t\in\Bbb Z_{11}\}$

Comment: I can't understand a single thing about what you said, and i studied every argument you cited, go figure...

Comment: Row-reduce mod $11$.  Correction on the cardinality part:  suppose the nullity is $2$.  Then the cardinality of the kernel would be $11^2=121$.

Comment: Please can you explain better the things you said? I row reduced the matrix, but then it's completely unclear what I have to do next. Please take your time but explain better

Comment: What is nullity?

Comment: Why the part b, which involves a 3x1 matrix, can be solved with row reduction of the first matrix?

Comment: Did you reduce everything mod $11$?  The nullity is the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: Please see my edit.